# Can't use 2560 x 1080 resolution on fedora

Tags: fedora, xrandr, monitors, resolution

I've just installed fedora on my laptop and it won't let me choose a resolution above 1920x1080.
I've tried xrandr but still can't change it.

All works on windows, using HDMI. Laptop has fedora 25, i7-3632QM, AMD 7730.
It also works on Ubuntu automatically.

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 2560x1080_60.00
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode 2560x1080_60.00

$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+0+1080 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     39.96*+
XWAYLAND2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 800mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     59.88*+
  2560x1080_60.00 (0x282) 230.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2720 end 2992 total 3424 skew    0 clock  67.17KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1093 total 1120           clock  59.98Hz
```

EDIT: I just did some research on what wayland was, does xrandr only work for X?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Try logging into "Gnome with Xorg" to see if that works. (click the gear under the password field in login screen)

Comment: I set Xorg to be the default. So I no longer saw wayland1, I saw hdmi1 when I ran xrandr. I still can't change the resolution though. Could this be a graphics driver problem? or does fedora ever work at 2560x1080? Here is the monitor https://www.amazon.com/LG-29UM68-P-29-Inch-21-UltraWide/dp/B01B9IDLAW

Comment: It could be a detection problem? How can it be a supported res and also exceed panel dimensions? I've tried refresh rates of 30, 45 and 60.
From Xorg.1.log__  intel(0): Not using mode "2560x1080_60.00" (exceeds panel dimensions)
__
[   110.333] (II) intel(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   110.333] (II) intel(0): clock: 185.6 MHz   Image Size:  798 x 334 mm
[   110.333] (II) intel(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2624  h_sync_end 2688 h_blank_end 2784 h_border: 0
[   110.333] (II) intel(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1083  v_sync_end 1093 v_blanking: 1111 v_border: 0